# Passar dados de uma Activity pra outra sem inicia-la?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou criando um App para Android, preciso passar dados de tipo String da primeira activity(quando iniciado), para uma terceira activity. Mas sem inicia-la. No caso eu pego o ID do usuário na primeira tela e a uso para cadastrar a mensagem, implementando-a no banco de dados.

Código:

```
//recebo assim do banco através do php
//Primeira Tela
String[] dados = result.split(",");
Intent abreHome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
abreHome.putExtra("id_user", dados[1]);

//Segunda Tela
//Recebo as Informações e repasso para a terceira
Intent abrePost = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
String id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_user");
startActivity(abrePost);
String txt = "";
txt = id_user.toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("txt", txt);
abrePost.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(abrePost);

//Terceira Tela
//Onde recebo o ID
//Porém quando eu executo, pela primeira vez a mensagem é salva, a segunda diz //que parou a Activity, e retorna para a segunda Activity.
//A primeira mensagem é salva, a segunda não, a terceira sim, a quarta não.
//E assim susessivamente
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
String txt = bundle.getString("txt");
id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("txt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está iniciando a mesma activity mais de uma vez, uma sem a informação que você deseja repassar e a outra com essa informação:

```
//Segunda Tela
//Recebo as Informações e repasso para a terceira
Intent abrePost = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
String id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_user");
startActivity(abrePost); //Inicia sem mensagem
String txt = "";
txt = id_user.toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("txt", txt);
abrePost.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(abrePost); //Inicia com mensagem
```

Para corrigir, é necessário apenas iniciar a activity quando ela possuir a informação que será repassada. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
//Segunda Tela
//Recebo as Informações e repasso para a terceira
Intent abrePost = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
String id_user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id_user");
String txt = "";
txt = id_user.toString();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("txt", txt);
abrePost.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(abrePost);
```

OBS: Lembre-se de controlar bem a inicialização de finalização das activities pois a abordagem utilizada por você nesse trecho de código gerará memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Você chamou sem querer duas vezes o `startActivity(abrePost);`